# Activating migration in a Asp.net5 project with Entity Framework 6

Tags: migration, entity-framework-6, asp.net-core

I am working on an project and tried know to activate the migration but when I open the Nugget package console and enter “enable-migrations myProjectName” I get the massage “The term 'Enable-Migrations' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet”. First I thought that I have to add an extra line in my project.json under commands, so I added “"ef": "EntityFramework.Commands" but that didn’t do the trick.”

Would be grateful for any pointers.

Answer (score 2):

You did mention you are using the `project.json` file  making me believe you are using the default ASP.NET 5 template which uses EF7 .

You can verify this by looking in your `project.json` at the version number.

Mine for example is:

```
"EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-beta8",
"EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-beta8",
```

or in  your Package Manager Console type in:

> get-command -module entityframework

[image]

which will give you the available commands you can use. From the above you can see I am using Entity Framework 7.

`Enable-Migrations` is not listed in the commands and that is the reason you are getting the error:

> The term 'Enable-Migrations' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

If you wish to rather use EF6 instead you would have to remove those entries in your `project.json` and you can add via `nuget` or the package manager console EF6. Just keep in mind if you use EF6 the ASP.NET 5 Identity 3 will break as it is dependent on EF7.

The command `Enable-Migrations` does not exist in `Entity Framework 7`  like it did in previous Entity framework versions.

In EF7 the task of creating the migrations folder is  now combined with the `Add-Migration` command.

See below for the `Add-Migration` command differences between EF6 and EF7:

[image]

Comment: I updated my answer, please verify the version in your project.json

Comment: You mentioned you use ASP.NET5 and the default ASP.NET5 template uses EF7 not EF6

Comment: I use the EF6 because when I started my project there were missing some functions in the EF7 I needed.
Project.json: "EntityFramework": "6.1.3"

Comment: and when you run "get-command -module entityframework" what does it say?

Comment: Nothing :(. I dont get an error put there is also no output in the Package Manager Console.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93774/discussion-between-sknecht-and-devc2).